# how can I install ccplot for python3.6 version and above

Tags: python-3.7

I tried this code following error i got

```
pip install ccplot
```

even i tried

```
conda install ccplot
```

ERROR: Failed building wheel for ccplot

Comment: ccplot is not supported for Python 3

Comment: @PeterSmith did u found any solution.